# Ionic4 watchPosition and getCurrentPosition of Geolocation not accurate with Ionic/Capacitor

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic4, ionic-native, capacitor

I'm using Capacitor for building my Ionic app.
I the app I wanna show the current position on a Map via GPS of course.

The following code works and gives me the correct Marker on the Map as I want to, but.. It's far from accurate.

```
async getLocation() {
    var self = this;
    let location = await Geolocation.getCurrentPosition({
        enableHighAccuracy: true,
        timeout: 1000
    });
    self.marker.setLngLat([location.coords.longitude, location.coords.latitude])
    const wait = Geolocation.watchPosition({enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: 1000}, (position, err) => {
        self.marker.setLngLat([position.coords.longitude, position.coords.latitude])
    });
}
```

The Marker is going around like crazy. Happens on every location I test it on. It's moving not centimeters, but meters around my location...

What am I missing that is giving me the less accurate GPS coordinates? I thought `enableHighAccuracy: true` was enough, but that's not it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Positional information can be returned from different location providers: satellite, network, passive. For the best results, you should discard locations provided by network and passive providers.

As far as I know, modern location apis do not differentiate between providers (cf. fused location), but you can always check `coords.accuracy` to get an overview of the accuracy of the position.

If the location is triangulated via satellites, accuracy will always be best. Usually **below 16** (measured in meters), but definitely **below 30**. You can safely discard coords with accuracy higher than that.

Comment: That was easy :-) Thanks

Comment: do you know what I'm doing wrong that I only get results higher then 50 for accuracy? @nikitah

Comment: This is mostly likely because (1) GPS isn't enabled, (2) high accuracy isn't enabled on your android phone or (3) you haven't explicitly requested permission. GPS module is a strong permission that needs to be requested from the user first: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation_API#Prompting_for_permission

Comment: has anyone found a solution to this?

Comment: @Nikitah I am facing an issue while getting geo-coordinates when my device isn't having a network/data connection/wifi. I have tried with (ACCESS_FINE_PERMISSION and ACCESS_COURSE). Could you please help me with this. I am using Ionic 4, enable high accuracy is also true.

Comment: I'm gonna need a more information because I can help you. I'm guessing you're on Android, but what OS version? Have you popped location permission dialog, i.e. does it even have GPS permission? Does everything work when network is enabled? Are you using a plugin or the web api?